# Query data by month and average in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Hoping someone can point me to the right direction here. I'm trying to make chart (from DB data) of average of daily production but in a monthly basis. so basically I have 30 rows of daily production and need to average them which I have no problem there, the AVG works fine but my issue is my x-axis which is the month. anyway to show 2016-01-01 7:00:00 to 2016-01-31 7:00:00 and show it as just the month (January in this case or even 1 works)?

Basically what needs to happen is I need one value in my x-axis and one in y-axis. x-axis is the month of the year and y-axis would be the average of production for that month. any ideas how I can tackle this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you tried the SQL [MONTH()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-date-functions.htm#function_month) function?

Comment: Use what ever the group by was.

Comment: Chris, Yes I assume I totally didn't follow the correct way of asking a question and I apologize, rookie mistake.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the edits. That's what happens when you try to type something at work really quick and don't get to review it. appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
Select xAxis=month(someDateField)
      ,yAxis=avg(someValueField)
 From  someTable
 Group By month(someDateField)
 Order By 1
```

Comment: damn... that GROUP BY month() got me, I was trying GROUP BY t_stamp... Thanks man !!!

Comment: Well done!   Not sure that the Union All piece it doing

Comment: you saw that? haha, I meant to delete it. I was trying each field that i need separately to make sure I get the right values and then combine them in one block.